# How to compile a file in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to update a class file in a jar Apache Maven.
Jar was compiled originally with 1.8.0_05 jdk. How can I compile it in order to be compatible with the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify where your repository is located. It might be in your `C:\users\{userprofile}\.m2` folder or it might be in a central location set by your Enterprise (and referenced in your project through an environment variable).

Under that repository folder is stored all `JARs` and `POMs`. You can find the location of the `JAR` you are looking for by looking at your project `POM` file and finding the `groupID` for that artifact. Once you find the one you need, you just extract it, make your changes, recompile and put it back and the run a `mvn clean install` on your project folder (where your main `POM` file is).

Comment: What command do I use for recompile? Simply javac *jar* *file*? and then run mvn clean install in the directory jar is?

Comment: Every file is compiled by Maven as part of the build lifecycle. (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) so what you are asking to do doesn't make sense. Most likely this JAR file is causing a problem due to some version error. Above I'm telling you how to get to that JAR file so you can figure out why it's not compiling correctly.

Comment: BTW you can identify what JRE version your maven is pointed to by running the command mvn -v